# How to convert Website to cordova apps?

Tags: cordova, webview, visual-studio-cordova

In visual studio community , how to convert website to cordova apps[web viewer].
Please, provide code for understanding .

Comment: [Visual Studio Tools 
for Apache Cordova](https://taco.visualstudio.com/)

Comment: Thanks for good information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to convert your website to a cordova app:
1. Follow these simple steps as shown [here](https://cordova.apache.org/) to create new project. 
2. Put the content of your index file into the cordova project's index file, make sure your js files are at the bottom of the index file.
3. Put the other files and website content on the webroot/public folder or accessible to the index file
4. Build the project.
That should get you started.